# Displaying selected option from database in a select option tag

Tags: php

This is a simple one, i know it is i just cant think of a good logical way to do this.

I have the following code:

```
<select name="Title[]" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select title...</option>
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
    <option value="Doctor">Doctor</option>
</select>
```

What i want to do is on my edit client page, have their previously selected option displayed. So for example, if Doctor was selected at sign up, it would be selected by default on the edit page. I know i could do this like:

```
<option value="Doctor" <?php if($client_title == 'Doctor'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Doctor</option>
```

But it seems like a bit of a redundant way to do it. Can this be done easily with a do while statement?

Sorry for the simple request, having a bit of a slow day today! haha

Comment: I'm assuming here that you **do** correctly wrap that code in PHP tags before you run it, but yeah, that's the way to do it - it's not redundant. You can reuse a variable at the top for the value, selected comparison and label to streamline it a bit

Comment: You could store your values altogether in an array and build the select via while - in this process of course you could also check if they were selected.

Comment: Well yeah haha i forgot to add those tags. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="title[]" class="form-control">
<?php
$titles = array('Mr', 'Miss', 'Mrs', 'Ms', 'Prof', 'Doctor');
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    $selected = $client_title == $title ? ' selected="selected"' : null;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $title; ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $title; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, i have used the code above as a template as there was an error and have simplified it to work perfectly. Thanks!